# Percentage label on pie chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a pie chart with the following data :

```
library (ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

> pie_brk_fam_H
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   fam [6]
  fam                  n     p
  <fct>            <int> <dbl>
1 Frullaniaceae      215  7.80
2 Lejeuneaceae       988 35.8 
3 Lepidoziaceae      349 12.7 
4 Mastigophoraceae   160  5.80
5 Plagiochilaceae    280 10.2 
6 Radulaceae         247  8.96


> dput(pie_brk_fam_H)
structure(list(fam = structure(c(14L, 20L, 21L, 24L, 30L, 37L
), .Label = c("Adelanthaceae", "Anastrophyllaceae", "Aneuraceae", 
"Balantiopsidaceae", "Bryaceae", "Calymperaceae", "Calypogeiaceae", 
"Cephaloziaceae", "Cephaloziellaceae", "Daltoniaceae", "Dendrocerotaceae", 
"Dicranaceae", "Fissidentaceae", "Frullaniaceae", "Grimmiaceae", 
"Herbertaceae", "Hypnaceae", "Jamesoniellaceae", "Jungermaniaceae", 
"Lejeuneaceae", "Lepidoziaceae", "Leucobryaceae", "Lophocoleaceae", 
"Mastigophoraceae", "Meteoriaceae", "Metzgeriaceae", "Neckeraceae", 
"Orthotrichaceae", "Pilotrichaceae", "Plagiochilaceae", "Pleuroziaceae", 
"Polytrichaceae", "Pottiaceae", "Pterobryaceae", "Pylaisiadelphaceae", 
"Racopilaceae", "Radulaceae", "Rhizogoniaceae", "Scapaniaceae", 
"Schistochilaceae", "Sematophyllaceae", "Serpotortellaceae", 
"Sphagnaceae"), class = "factor"), n = c(215L, 988L, 349L, 160L, 
280L, 247L), p = c(7.79833151976786, 35.8360536815379, 12.6586869785999, 
5.80340950308306, 10.1559666303954, 8.95901342038448)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), groups = structure(list(fam = structure(c(14L, 20L, 21L, 
24L, 30L, 37L), .Label = c("Adelanthaceae", "Anastrophyllaceae", 
"Aneuraceae", "Balantiopsidaceae", "Bryaceae", "Calymperaceae", 
"Calypogeiaceae", "Cephaloziaceae", "Cephaloziellaceae", "Daltoniaceae", 
"Dendrocerotaceae", "Dicranaceae", "Fissidentaceae", "Frullaniaceae", 
"Grimmiaceae", "Herbertaceae", "Hypnaceae", "Jamesoniellaceae", 
"Jungermaniaceae", "Lejeuneaceae", "Lepidoziaceae", "Leucobryaceae", 
"Lophocoleaceae", "Mastigophoraceae", "Meteoriaceae", "Metzgeriaceae", 
"Neckeraceae", "Orthotrichaceae", "Pilotrichaceae", "Plagiochilaceae", 
"Pleuroziaceae", "Polytrichaceae", "Pottiaceae", "Pterobryaceae", 
"Pylaisiadelphaceae", "Racopilaceae", "Radulaceae", "Rhizogoniaceae", 
"Scapaniaceae", "Schistochilaceae", "Sematophyllaceae", "Serpotortellaceae", 
"Sphagnaceae"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I managed to make the graph but not to display the percentages correctly. Here is my code :

```
pie_brk_fam_H <- pie_brk_fam_H %>% mutate(pos = cumsum(p)- p/2)

ggplot(data=pie_brk_fam_H, aes(x=factor(1), y=p, fill=factor(fam))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(x= factor(1), y=pos, label = p), size=10) + 
  coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

Here is my graph :

[image]

I guess I did something wrong in the labels position part. The other topics close to this subject on the forum didn't helped me.

Comment: simply try `geom_text(aes(label = round(p,2)), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),size=6)`

Comment: Thank you I go it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
ggplot(data=pie_brk_fam_H, aes(x=factor(1), y=p, fill=factor(fam))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(p,2)), size=7,position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + 
  coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image]

Comment: you changed the size parameter, but the answer  is the same as I provided in the comments. Its ok, but please refer to my comment.